Connect to Azure AD with service principal to get a listing of users and info
I'm trying to connect to Azure AD and get a listing of accounts that match a specific company and get a file with the account info. The script works if I use an interactive login, but I need to automate this with the service principal login. I get an error at get-azureaduser in this script - what am I doing wrong?
# Connect to Azure AD
$tenantId = "xxxxxxx"
$clientId = "xxxxxxx"
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx"

import-module az

$secureClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientId,    $secureClientSecret)
 
Connect-Azaccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $credential

# Define the company name to filter by
$companyName = "some company"

# Get users from Azure AD, filter by company name and job title, and select required properties
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {
    $_.CompanyName -eq $companyName -and $_.JobTitle -ne $null
    } | Select-Object DisplayName, JobTitle, Mail, Department

# Export the filtered users to a CSV file
$users | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\Users.csv" -NoTypeInformation

I tried adding
$currentAzureContext = Get-AzContext
$tenantId = $currentAzureContext.Tenant.Id
$accountId = $currentAzureContext.Account.Id
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -AccountId $accountId

but that also brings up a login prompt


Note that: Azure AD PowerShell module supports service principal authentication or gives no prompt only when CertificateThumbprint and ApplicationId are passed. Refer this MsDoc

Hence make use of Connect-AzureAD and modify the script like below:
# Define your tenant ID, application ID, and certificate thumbprint
$tenantId = "TenantID"
$applicationId = "APPID"
$certThumbprint = "CertTumbPrint"

# Connect to Azure AD using the certificate
Connect-AzureAD -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint -ApplicationId $applicationId -TenantId $tenantId

# Define the company name to filter by
$companyName = "ruk"

$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {
    $_.CompanyName -eq $companyName -and $_.JobTitle -ne $null
    } | Select-Object DisplayName, JobTitle, Mail, Department

# Export the filtered users to a CSV file
$users | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\v-rukmini\Downloads\rukcsvaad.csv" -NoTypeInformation



Make sure to upload certificate in the Microsoft Entra ID application:


The .cer certificate must be uploaded to the  Microsoft Entra ID application
The .pfx certificate must be present in the local machine where you are executing the code.
Otherwise, make use of Connect-Azaccount -ServicePrincipal and use Get-AzADUser


using certthumbprint worked! thanks. follow up question what permissions does the service principal need exactly. I have the following assigned but get a permission error. if I assign user admin role to the app then it works. but I am uncomfortable adding that role to the app.Directory.Read.All
Read directory data
Group.Read.All
Read all groups
Yes
profile
View users' basic profile
User.Read
Sign in and read user profile
User.Read.All
Read all users' full profiles

Please post a new question with all details and share the link here

@Rukmini https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78822469/minimum-permissions-that-are-required-for-serviceprincipal-account-to-enumerate

Sure will check
