minimum permissions that are required for serviceprincipal account to enumerate user profile info
what permissions does the service principal need to enumerate user profile info i.e. department, email, etc..
I have the following assigned but get a permission error. if I assign user admin role to the app then it works. but I am uncomfortable adding that role to the app.



Note that: Connecting to Azure AD PowerShell module requires assigning of Directory Readers role (in your scenario) to the app registration along with API permissions too. Refer this blog by NoVestigeOfBeginning.

Without assigning roles I got error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation":

To get the user profile information grant User.Read.All application API permission:

And add active assignment of Directory readers role to the application:


I am able to fetch user's profile based on your requirement successfully:
# Define your tenant ID, application ID, and certificate thumbprint
$tenantId = "TenantID"
$applicationId = "APPID"
$certThumbprint = "CertTumbPrint"

# Connect to Azure AD using the certificate
Connect-AzureAD -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint -ApplicationId $applicationId -TenantId $tenantId

# Define the company name to filter by
$companyName = "ruk"

$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {
    $_.CompanyName -eq $companyName -and $_.JobTitle -ne $null
    } | Select-Object DisplayName, JobTitle, Mail, Department

# Export the filtered users to a CSV file
$users 


Otherwise, make use of Microsoft Graph PowerShell module as Azure AD PowerShell module will be deprecated:

The below requires User.Read.All application type API permissions granted to the application.
There is no need add any other Microsoft Entra ID roles to make it work.

# Define your tenant ID, client ID, and certificate thumbprint
$tenantId     = "TenantID"
$clientId     = "ClientID"
$certThumbprint = "CertThumbprint"
$companyName  = "ruk"

# Connect to Microsoft Graph using client credentials and certificate
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint

# Retrieve users with filtering and selecting specific properties
$filteredUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter "companyName eq '$companyName' and jobTitle ne null" `
                            -Select "displayName,jobTitle,mail,department" `
                            -CountVariable CountVar `
                            -ConsistencyLevel Eventual

# Output the filtered users
$filteredUsers | Format-Table -Property displayName, jobTitle, mail, department -AutoSize



You can also make use of invoke rest method as suggested by @wenbo.

Reference:
Use Microsoft Graph PowerShell authentication commands | Microsoft
UPDATE:
To get the results use Top operator:
# Define your tenant ID, client ID, and certificate thumbprint
$tenantId        = "TenantID"
$clientId        = "ClientID"
$certThumbprint  = "CertThumbprint"
$companyName     = "ruk"
$topResults      = 500

# Connect to Microsoft Graph using client credentials and certificate
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint

# Retrieve users with filtering, selecting specific properties, and limiting the number of results
$filteredUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter "companyName eq '$companyName' and jobTitle ne null" `
                            -Select "displayName,jobTitle,mail,department" `
                            -Top $topResults `
                            -CountVariable CountVar `
                            -ConsistencyLevel Eventual

# Output the filtered users
$filteredUsers | Format-Table -Property displayName, jobTitle, mail, department -AutoSize


that works. if I want to export the results should $filteredUsers | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\File.csv" -NoTypeInformation  work?

Try `# Export the filtered users to a CSV file
$csvFilePath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Output\filteredUsers.csv"
$filteredUsers | Select-Object displayName, jobTitle, mail, department | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
Output the filtered users to the console in a table format
$filteredUsers | Format-Table -Property displayName, jobTitle, mail, department -AutoSize`

The export works but I get only get a partial list of users if I use the graph. I get 394 users with the first powershell script but only 101 with graph. why would that be?

Check my updated answer

that worked. Thanks! @Rukmini

Use.Read.All with Application Type is enough, but remember to grant admin consent request (a green dot will appear). such as:

department and email user info will be show with select query, If no select query, department info will be hidden
Sample code: with get use microsoft graph rest api
$tenantId           = ""
$clientId           = ""
$clientSecret       = ""

$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
}

$token = $(Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body -Headers $headers).access_token


$objectId = ""

$headers2 = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $token
}

$uri2 = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}?`$select=displayName,givenName,mail,department" -f $objectId

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri2 -Headers $headers2

$response

Test result:

